# Pushing new files to new repo

Tags: git, bitbucket

I'm trying to push an existing set of files to a new private repo I've created. I've done this before, but today I'm getting a different output than usual.

Upon pushing, I got the following message:

```
Warning: Permanently added the RSA host key for IP address '131.103.20.168' to the list of known hosts.

Permission denied (publickey).
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.
```

First, I noticed that the instructions for setting up a new repo has changed to use `SSH` instead of `HTTPS` to push to a repo:

```
cd /path/to/my/repo
git remote add origin git@bitbucket.org:renovationlabs/cloudcode.git
git push -u origin --all # pushes up the repo and its refs for the first time
git push -u origin --tags # pushes up any tags
```

Now I'm met with these warnings and errors. Is this an `SSH` issue, and how can I fix this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `git@bitbucket.org/` means that the communication with bitbucket will be made using an SSH key.

You can do two thing

1. Setup a SSH key on your computer and had it to bitbucket so we can recognize you
2. set you origin to something like `https//(UserName)@bitbucket.org:renovationlabs/cloudcode.git`. This way you use https communication with bitbucket.

Bitbucket explains how to set up an ssh key here:

https://confluence.atlassian.com/bitbucket/set-up-ssh-for-git-728138079.html